# ForceCommand vs Subsystem

Tags: ssh, shell, sftp

Is there any particula reason why I should use

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

instead of

```
Subsystem sftp iternal-sftp
```

and disabling the shell?

Comment: you should read `man sshd_config` about both of these options.

Comment: I did but dont see any difference using them separately apart from the logging output